# Gain Reputation for Proving Competence

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Let's say you program as a hobby. You have a few good open source projects on the internet. You discover StackOverflow and decide to join. There should be a way for you to prove that you are a good programmer by linking to your open-source code. If enough people up vote your request, you should gain some reputation.

Example: I sign up for StackOverflow and put in a request to receive reputation based on the fact that I have a lot of good projects available. Some people look at the code on my GitHub page and decide that I am in fact competent. They up vote my request and, when I get enough votes, I receive some reputation. The same could be applied to most other websites.

Comment: How can we know you wrote it, also who is going to spend the hour assessing your work

Comment: Then how would professional programmers, whose code is not publicly available, be able to gain similar reputation?  This would be unfair.  It would also be extraordinarily difficult to achieve.

Comment: a) Most online posting sites (definitely GitHub) have APIs. b) Does it take hours to see that there are some powerful projects in your repo? c) @Chenmunka I can't say. Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: It *would* take hours to determine whether it's good code, that it's actually written by the person claiming it.... it would be abused without end. There is massive abuse of the voting system going on all the time. But that at least sometimes has a chance of being discovered and fixed. How would you do that when people starting claiming code for themselves that they've lifted from somewhere else? It's a nice idea and it would be cool if this were possible - it's become harder to gain rep on SO, no doubt. But it would be a catastrophe to implement.

Comment: down votes on Meta mean disagreement ;-)

Comment: What would be the point of this? Stack Overflow is a programming question and answer site, not a programmer rating site.

Comment: You're misunderstanding reputation. Rep is an indicator of how much the community trusts you, not of how good a programmer you are.

Comment: If you're a competent programmer, you should have no trouble gaining rep by answering questions.

Comment: I know of one pretty good programmer that has earned himself a network wide ban. The community does **not** trust him anymore. Programming prowess != community reputation.

Answer (score 18):

This would be a nightmare to implement:

- It would take a long time to assess your work, without the motivation from helping many other people (rather than just you). I'm not sure many people would volunteer for this.
- It would be impossible to know it was your code rather than stolen code.
- It is unfairly biased towards open source programmers. Anyone who works largely on closed source programs is unfairly penalised.

It shouldn't be implemented anyway:

- Rep is a measure of how much **this** community trusts you; you shouldn't get that just by an assessment from one person.
- Rep opens up moderator tools - for this you need to understand the community, not just the subject.

And of course this is very Stack Overflow centric, this wouldn't work for other sites in the Stack Exchange network